# getting Base64 cannot be resolved at Decryptor... while trying to decrypt file

Tags: java, encryption, base64

I'm writing a program that decrypt a file that was encrypted.

i recive the folowing output:

```
==============================
== Receiver\Decryptor side ==
==============================
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Base64 cannot be resolved
    Base64 cannot be resolved
    Base64 cannot be resolved

    at Decryptor.DecryptFileAndValidateSignature(Decryptor.java:97)
    at Decryptor.main(Decryptor.java:65)
```

the error happens somwhere at these 3 lines -

```
ks.load(ksStream, receiverConfigurations.get("keyStorePass").toCharArray());
/* Loads private key from keyStore, needed to decrypt the symmetric key from configuration file    */
PrivateKey receiverPrivateKey =  (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(receiverConfigurations.get("receiverAlias"), receiverConfigurations.get("receiverKeyPass").toCharArray()); //private key of receiver
```

i guess something is wring with my imports.. 
as you can see i tried a lot. any help will be aprricated tnx
here is my code -

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64InputStream;



public class Decryptor {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        if (args.length!=2)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong number of parameters, please insert the path of encryptedTextFile.txt, cipherConfigurations.xml and the path for keystore file.\n" +
                    "Make sure that path is ended with '\\\\'. Example:  c:\\\\test\\\\crypto\\\\keyStore.jks c:\\\\test\\\\crypto\\\\"
                    +   "\nAborting...\n");

            return;
        }
        if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(args[0])))
        {
            System.out.println("Path "+args[0]+" doesn't exist.\nAborting...\n");
            return;
        }
        String basePath = args[0];
        String keyStore = args[1];
        basePath = "c:\\test\\crypto\\";

        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("==============================");
        System.out.println("== Receiver\\Decryptor side ==");
        System.out.println("==============================");
        /* Configurations that are known to the receiver */
        HashMap<String,String> receiverConfigurations = new HashMap<>();
        receiverConfigurations.put("encryptedTextFile" ,basePath+"encryptedTextFile.txt");
        receiverConfigurations.put("configurationFile",basePath+"cipherConfigurations.xml");
        receiverConfigurations.put("keyStorePass","gilperryB");
        receiverConfigurations.put("receiverAlias","b_side");
        receiverConfigurations.put("receiverKeyPass","gilperryB");
        receiverConfigurations.put("decryptedTextFile",basePath+"decryptedText.txt");
        receiverConfigurations.put("keyStorePath",keyStore);
        receiverConfigurations.put("senderAlias","a_side");

        DecryptFileAndValidateSignature(receiverConfigurations);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    /* 
     * Decrypts and validates a signature of an encrypted file that was sent between a sender and a receiver, in the following way:
     * 1. Uses private key to encrypt a symmetric key from a configuration file.
     * 2. Uses the symmetric key to decrypt the message sent in a different file
     * 3. Calculates digital signature over the file, and compares it with the one received in the configuration file.
     * 4. If the signatures match - returns true, else - returns false
     * */ 
    static public boolean DecryptFileAndValidateSignature(HashMap<String,String> receiverConfigurations) throws Exception
    {
        /* Load data from keyStore .jks file */
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks"); // Load public key from keyStore
        FileInputStream ksStream = new FileInputStream(receiverConfigurations.get("keyStorePath"));
        ks.load(ksStream, receiverConfigurations.get("keyStorePass").toCharArray());

        /* Loads private key from keyStore, needed to decrypt the symmetric key from configuration file */
        PrivateKey receiverPrivateKey =  (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(receiverConfigurations.get("receiverAlias"), receiverConfigurations.get("receiverKeyPass").toCharArray()); //private key of receiver

        /* Load data received by the cipher configurations XML sent by sender */
        HashMap<String,String> cipherConfigurations = ReadConfigurationXML(receiverConfigurations.get("configurationFile"));
        if (cipherConfigurations == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Error reading cipher configurations XML.\nAborting...");
        }
        System.out.println("Read data Cipher configurations XML.");         
        /* Initialize the encryptor */
        Cipher encryptor = Cipher.getInstance(cipherConfigurations.get("encryptionAlgoForSymmetricKey"), cipherConfigurations.get("encryptionAlgoForSymmetricKeyProvider"));

        /* Get data from cipher configurations XML*/
        byte[] symetricKeyEncrypted = Base64.decodeBase64(cipherConfigurations.get("symetricKeyEncrypted"));
        /* Initialize the symmetric key encryptor */
        Cipher rsaEncryptor = Cipher.getInstance(cipherConfigurations.get("encryptionAlgoForSendingSharedKey"), cipherConfigurations.get("encryptionAlgoForSendingSharedKeyProvider")); // encryptor for the secret key
        byte[] symetricKeyDecrypted = DecryptText(symetricKeyEncrypted,rsaEncryptor,receiverPrivateKey, null);

        byte[] ivConfig =Base64.decodeBase64(cipherConfigurations.get("ivspec"));
        byte[] iv = DecryptText(ivConfig, rsaEncryptor, receiverPrivateKey, null);
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        byte[] digitalSignature = Base64.decodeBase64(cipherConfigurations.get("digitalSignature"));

        Key symmetricKeyAfterDecription =  new SecretKeySpec(symetricKeyDecrypted, cipherConfigurations.get("encryptionAlgoForKeyGeneration")); //build a new secret key from text
        System.out.println("Decrypted symmetric key using his own private key");

        /* Decrypt file into decryptedFile */
        DecryptFile(receiverConfigurations.get("encryptedTextFile"), receiverConfigurations.get("decryptedTextFile"), encryptor, symmetricKeyAfterDecription,ivSpec);
        System.out.println("Decrypted text file "+receiverConfigurations.get("encryptedTextFile")+" into "+receiverConfigurations.get("decryptedTextFile"));        

        /* Verify digital signature */
        PublicKey senderPublicKey = ks.getCertificate(receiverConfigurations.get("senderAlias")).getPublicKey(); //publicKey holds the public key for sender
        boolean signatureValidated = ValidateDigitalSignature(receiverConfigurations.get("decryptedTextFile"),cipherConfigurations.get("digitalSignatureAlgorithm"),senderPublicKey,digitalSignature);

        if (!signatureValidated)
        {
            System.out.println("Error decrypting text or validating digital signature.\nAborting...");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("File was successfully decrypted, digital signature was successfully validated.\n");
            return true;
        }

       }


    /* 
     * Simulates the process where the receiver is calculating the signature of a message he received
     * and compares it to the signature sent to him by sender.
     * Calculates the digital signature over the decrypted file, using the digital signature algorithm in digitalSignatureAlgorithm,
     * and public key in senderPublicKey.
     * returns true iff the signatures match.
     *  */
    private static boolean ValidateDigitalSignature(String decryptedFile,
        String digitalSignatureAlgorithm, PublicKey senderPublicKey, byte[] signatureToVerify) throws Exception {
        Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance(digitalSignatureAlgorithm);       /* Initializing the object with the digital signature algorithm */ 
        dsa.initVerify(senderPublicKey); 
        /* Update and sign the data */ 
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(decryptedFile); 
        byte[] block = new byte[8];
        int i;
        while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) { //read all blocks in file
            dsa.update(block); // update digital signature after each block 
        }
        fis.close();
        return dsa.verify(signatureToVerify);

        }

    /* 
     * Reads an encrypted text file and decrypts it using a Cipher object (encryptor).
     * The decrypted file will be the returned value.
     * Decryption process contains also Base64 encoding of the text.
     */
    private static void DecryptFile(String inputFile,String outputFile, Cipher encryptor, Key key, IvParameterSpec ivspec) throws Exception
    {
        assert (CreateFileIfNecessery(outputFile) == true); //creates output file if necessery
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        Base64InputStream b64os = new Base64InputStream(fis);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(b64os, encryptor);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        encryptor.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivspec); //initilize cipher in decryption mode with IV

        byte[] block = new byte[8];
        int i;
        while ((i = cis.read(block)) != -1) { //read all blocks in file
            {
                fos.write(block,0,i); // write each block encrypted to the output file
            }
        }
        b64os.close();
        fos.close(); // close output file
        cis.close(); // close input file
    }

    /* 
     * Reads the configuration XML from file in 'path'.
     * Retuns a HashMap containing the entries and their value.
     * if not possible - returns null.
     */

    public static HashMap<String,String> ReadConfigurationXML(String path) throws Exception
    {
        HashMap<String,String> cipherConfigurations = new HashMap<>();
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc;

        try{
        doc = builder.parse(path);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error reading configurations file "+path+"\nAborting...");
            return null;
        }

        NodeList mainNode = null;
        try
        {
            mainNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("CipherConfigurations");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not find element EncryptionConfigurations in the configurations file.\nAborting...");
            return null;
        }

        if (mainNode.getLength()!=1)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong structure of cipher configutarion element.\nAborting...");
            return null;
        }

        NodeList cipherConfigurationsRoot = (NodeList) mainNode.item(0); // get the root element of the configurations
        for (int i = 0; i < cipherConfigurationsRoot.getLength(); ++i)
        {
            Element elem = (Element) cipherConfigurationsRoot.item(i);
            String paramName = elem.getNodeName();
            String innerText = elem.getTextContent();
            cipherConfigurations.put(paramName, innerText);
        }
        return cipherConfigurations;
    }

    /* 
     * Reads an encrypted text and decrypts it using a Cipher object (encryptor).
     * The decrypted text will be the returned value.
     * Decryption process contains also Base64 encoding of the text.
     */
    public static byte[] DecryptText(byte[] text, Cipher encryptor, Key key, IvParameterSpec ivspec) throws Exception
    {
        OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text);
        Base64InputStream b64is = new Base64InputStream(is);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(b64is, encryptor);
        encryptor.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivspec); //initilize cipher in decryption mode with IV
        byte[] block = new byte[8];
        int i;  
        while ((i = cis.read(block)) != -1) { //read all blocks in file
            {
                os.write(block,0, i); // write each block encrypted to the output file
            }
        }
        b64is.close();
        os.close(); // close output file
        is.close(); // close input file
        cis.close();
        return ((ByteArrayOutputStream) os).toByteArray();
    }

    /* 
     * Creates file and its paths if not exist.
     * Example: path = c:\\test\\test1\\foo.txt
     * Method will check if this path and file exists, if not - will create full hierarchy.
     */
    private static boolean CreateFileIfNecessery(String path) throws Exception
    {
        File f = new File(path);
        if (!f.mkdirs()) return false; //creates the directories for the file
        if (!f.createNewFile()) return false; // creates the output file
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Im new here and having problems with editing also.. sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing Apache's `commons-codec-1.10.jar`

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

if you're using Maven